# How can I move columns based on the column header title to another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have to average grades based on each objective for a new report card we have to complete this year. Column one has students names, each additional column will have the objective associated with the assignment. I would like to move the entire column to another sheet based on the objective.

For example;

- objective 3.1A is in columns 2, 5, and 7
- objective 3.2B is located in columns 1, 4, 10, and 12
- objective 3.4c is in column 3, 6, 9, and 11

I would like to have a spreadsheet for each objective. Is there a formula or macro that will do that?